# Extinction Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Suppose that lions have a geometric offspring distribution.
$p_{k}=(1-\theta)\theta^{k}$, $k\geq 0$
with mean 1.5. If the current world population of lions is 10, what is the probability they will go extinct in 1 generation? What is the probability they will go extinct eventually?

Same two questions whose offspring distribution is Poisson with mean 0.8, and current population is 5000.

Comment: What the relation between the lions and the rabbits?

Comment: Oops! sorry, I started writing the wrong question.

Comment: I don't understand what value $\theta$ would have... and how to use the mean for this.

Comment: The mean would be $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp_k$. Setting this equal to $1.5$, we should be able to solve for $\theta$.

Comment: So,we have $p_{1}+2p_{2}+...=1.5...$ where does $\theta$ come in?

Comment: We have that equation and that $p_{0}=1-\theta$, $p_{1}=(1-\theta)\theta$, $p_{2}=(1-\theta)\theta^{2}$,...etc.

Comment: This gives us $(1-\theta)\theta+2((1-\theta)\theta^{2})+3((1-\theta)\theta^{3})+...$  I'm not sure what to do now though.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
1.5
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k}{k-1}(1-\theta)\theta^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{k-1}(-1)^{k-1}(1-\theta)\theta^k\\
&=(1-\theta)\theta(1-\theta)^{-2}\\
&=\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}
\end{align}
$$
Solve for $\theta$.

Comment: I found $\theta=0.6$
Then, $p_{0}^{10}=(1-0.6)0.6^{0}=0.4^{10}=0.0001048576$.

Comment: How can I find the probability of eventual extinction?

Comment: Actually, I figured out the first one. Could someone help me figure out how to do it for a Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Refer to Branching Process

Suppose every member gives birth independently to an identically distributed number of "children", $X$ is the number of offspring. If $P(X=0)>0$
$$ P(the\ process\ will\ go\ extinct)=1 \iff\ \mathbb{E}X\le 1
$$
I think then you know how to deal with it.

When $\mathbb{E}X>1$, and you want to compute $P(the\ process\ will\ go\ extinct)$, then you need to use the generating function for $X$.